# mapStateToProps and variable is not defined React-Redux

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am getting this error:

> ./src/components/Playing.jsx
>     Line 15:  'aaa' is not defined  no-undef

in my Playing.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

console.log(aaa);
```

From my Token.jsx

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
imports { Playing } from '../components/Playing'

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  aaa: "asdf"
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Playing)
```

Comment: I recommend you brush up on "scope" and "closures" (and any other basic JS you're missing)

Comment: And you might want to read up a bit on React components with and without Redux.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to just `console.log()` anywhere in the file; it would need to be within some function of the `Playing` component; and it will also only be available via `props`, e.g.

```
class Playing extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.aaa);
  }

  render() {
    return <span>Playing</span>;
  }
}
```

Comment: it is consoled as "undefined"

Comment: Am I obligues to use reducers if I use `mapState/DispatchToProps` ?

Comment: yes, the state in `mapStateToProps` comes from your `store` which is comprised of 1 or more reducers